# Set creator automatically with DjangoRestFramework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a creator field. I want this field to be initialized to the person that created the model instance and not be modifyable later on.

The creator field looks like this:

```
creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

And in the DRF HyperlinkedModelSerializer I have this:

```
read_only_fields = ('creator',)
```

Now the problem is I of course can't create new instances anymore since the creator field is not set. how can I achieve that?

One possible solution seems to be this

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    validated_data['creator'] = self.context['request'].user
    return models.MyModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Is this the dry way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [CreateOnlyDefault](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#createonlydefault) and [CurrentUserDefault](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) and define creator as `read_only` with a `default` value on your Serializer:

```
creator = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    read_only=True,
    default=serializers.CreateOnlyDefault(serializers.CurrentUserDefault()),
    view_name=...
)
```

This is my preferred way of doing this as you see directly from the Serializer definition the `creator` field is treated specially.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Didn't know this combination would work.

Comment: Hmm I just noticed that it actually does not wok! Yes on creation the creator is set, that's great. But on put and patch by a different user the creator is updated to the last user. So it now is more a last_modified_by field.

Comment: Hmm I think the following is the correct implementation:     creator = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='user-detail', read_only=True, default=serializers.CreateOnlyDefault(serializers.CurrentUserDefault()))

Comment: Indeed, it gets updated on all requests, and yes combining it with `CreateOnlyDefault` is the way to restrict it to creations only. I have updated the answer.